# How to compile pandoc pipe tables into html?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

This [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247003/13173) is about how to do this with multiline tables. 
However, I need more stricter syntax in raw data to have better secondary data computation with AWK and Gnuplot in drafting notes.

### Pandoc Pipe tables

Raw data

```
-------------------------------------------------
Size      | File  |  EventSize | W.Events | fafa  
----------|-------|------------|----------|------
L805067   | 009   | L805+4     | 1000     |  -      
L805067   | 001   |  L805+4    | 1000     |  - 
-------------------------------------------------
```

The [manual](http://pandoc.org/README.html) says that the extension `+pipe_tables` could be added to markdown.
I run unsuccessfully the following but not get fields separated by HTML syntax:

```
pandoc data.tex -f markdown+pipe_tables -t html
```

giving only (I get the same output also without the extension)

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="left">Size | File | EventSize | W.Events | fafa</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td align="left">----------|-------|------------|----------|------</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="left">L805067 | 009 | L805+4 | 1000 | -</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td align="left">L805067 | 001 | L805+4 | 1000 | -</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

### Correct output

```
<table>
<colgroup>
<col width="15%" />
<col width="12%" />
<col width="16%" />
<col width="13%" />
<col width="9%" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th align="left">Size</th>
<th align="center">File</th>
<th align="left">EventSize</th>
<th align="left">W.Events</th>
<th align="left">fafa</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="left">L805067</td>
<td align="center">009</td>
<td align="left">L805+4</td>
<td align="left">1000</td>
<td align="left">-</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td align="left">L805067</td>
<td align="center">001</td>
<td align="left">L805+4</td>
<td align="left">1000</td>
<td align="left">-</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

which can be generated by the following table with the same command `pandoc /tmp/1.tex -f markdown -t html`:

```
-------------------------------------------------
Size        File    EventSize   W.Events  fafa
---------- -------  ----------- --------  -------
L805067     009     L805+4      1000       -

L805067     001     L805+4      1000       -
-------------------------------------------------
```

### Pandoc [Ugly](http://pandoc.org/README.html) pipe tables

I got a piece of advice to use ugly tables [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247003/13173):

```
-------------------------------------------------
Size      | File  |  EventSize | W.Events | fafa
----------|-------|------------|----------|----:
L805067   | 009   | L805+4     | 1000     |  -
L805067   | 001   |  L805+4    | 1000     |  -
-------------------------------------------------
```

but running `pandoc /tmp/1.tex -f markdown -t html` gives the same unsuccessful output as above with pipe tables.

### Two tables after Kurt's comment

Test data where I left out the ":" -marks

```
Asetukset
--------------------------------------------------
Virta I = 1-100 nA

Resistanssi R = 5 T\Omega

Table: Asetukset elektromateriaaliselle virralle.



Tilanteet
---------------------------------------------
tasainen virta

muuttuva virta

kuormitus

Table: Elektrokarakteristiset ominaisuudet.
```

which yields wrongly

[image]

by the code presented in the current answer.

OS: Debian 8.5, OS X El Capitan
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA, Macbook Air 2013-mid

Comment: pipe tables do not allow multiline content. They will not work with a line of dashes at the end. Remove the empty line and the last one. You also have a missing pipe between W.Events and fafa

Comment: @scoa Thank you for your comment! I corrected the typo but still I get wrong output. I got the same output with the extension `+pipe_tables`  and without.

Comment: Try removing the last line too : `-------------------------------------------------`. You don't need to add `+pipe_tables` : "Pandoc’s enhanced version of markdown includes syntax for footnotes, tables, flexible ordered lists, definition lists, fenced code blocks, superscript, subscript, strikeout, title blocks, automatic tables of contents, embedded LaTeX math, citations, and markdown inside HTML block elements." (from pandoc's manual)

Comment: @scoa Works! Please, make that an answer! Why you cannot use the last line of dashes? Actually, I can also live without such a line at the end :)

Comment: The first line, `-------------------------------------------------` as well as the last (identical) line are not part of the `pipe_tables` syntax! (What you *should* have though, is a blank line above and below the table...)

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Thank you for your comment! I added an example of two tables -data where I applied the shell script of scoa's answer. How can you proceed here to correct output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The general rules

There are three different problems with your tables. Two are related to incorrect formatting : dash ligns (ligns containing just three or more `-`) and empty lines. The last one is about one-column tables.

1. A dash line can be interpreted in pandoc as :

   - An horizontal rules (`<hr/>` in html)
   - A marker that the text on the previous line is level 2 Setext-style headers
   - A beginning and ending marker of a *multiline* table (and only a multiline table : they do not work for pipe tables, simple tables or grid tables)
2. Empty lines in tables are *only allowed for multiline tables* (they do not work for simple, pipe and grid tables). In multiline tables, they are used as a row separator.
3. It seems that one-column tables are not recognized by pandoc if they are not *preceded* by a table caption. This is probably because there is no other way to differentiate a one-column table from a level-2 header otherwise.

### Why the current tables do not work as expected

Your first table is an incorrect pipe table. It has two dash lines, one at the beginning and one at the end.

The "Two tables after Kurt's comment" you added are also incorrect. They have blank lines, but do not have the other properties of a multiline table (namely an opening and ending dash line).

### What would work

Be consistent with table types : don't use any dash line or any blank lines for pipe tables. Be careful to add a table caption before the table if it has only one column.

`pandoc test.md -o test.pdf`

```
Size      | File  |  EventSize | W.Events | fafa  
----------|-------|------------|----------|------
L805067   | 009   | L805+4     | 1000     |  -      
L805067   | 001   |  L805+4    | 1000     |  - 

Table: Title

Table: Asetukset elektromateriaaliselle virralle.

Asetukset
--------------------------------------------------
Virta I = 1-100 nA
Resistanssi R = 5 T$$\Omega$$


Table: Elektrokarakteristiset ominaisuudet.

Tilanteet
---------------------------------------------
tasainen virta
muuttuva virta
kuormitus
```

[image]

Comment: Manuals seems to be wrong. Headings are possible. I just added an example about them, picture and code to have them.